# How can one increase the life span and youth?

Tags: halal-haram, dua, death

I have a question which is about death. I know that God Almighty has fixed everyone's age for death to arrive to one of them. I wonder if for example I'm 18 years old and I’m very healthy person without being poisoned nor shot and plus I’m young, but simply I have to die at age of 21, can I make *Supplication to God* To Make my death not to be at age of 21 but to be at age of 200, to have more time to enjoy my life and youth,  and to do more preparations and to do things I haven't do?

Oh, and is there any Dua that will change the date of death? And a Dua or something to say or something to do, so that my youth will be increased? Because, I’d like at age of 60 or 70 to look young in biological point. Because, it’s yak to look old man, I don’t like to look like an old man. I want to have a strong energy and I want to be also a strong person, and do things like: visiting places I never visited, performing more prayers and so on, in such that will make me be sure that I will be rewarded in my grave. Because right now, this is the beginning where I just started somehow to follow the teachings of Quran and prophet Muhammad and God, and if I were to die at age of 19, then I’ll be scared even 1h before death.

**My question is:** if I can make this *Supplication to God* which I have mentioned in text? And if: yes, then what are the supplications as I mentioned here on text? You can add also something from Quran.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Refer to [why we should avoid asking multi-question questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/).

Comment: @III-AK-III Is that ok now?

Comment: @III-AK-III I don’t know what just happened, but by mistake it has been deleted or removed the answer

Comment: Yes, the question is now focused.

Comment: @III-AK-III Why I don’t get any answer? I ask curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a brief answer to explain you.

Firstly remember ,as Muslims  that this life is not eternal. You have to die one day. Either  it be at age of 1,20,200 or 500 etc.
Who does not want to live young forever?.But there is a life cycle for everything.

---

> *"to have more time to enjoy my life and youth, and to do more preparations and to do things I haven't do?"*

.

If your niyah(intention) is that if Allah give me more age I will spend more time in prayers/reciting Quran then InshaAllah (by will of ALLAH) you will get that reward 
because It is the  first hadith of Sahi Bukhari:
"`Actions are dependent upon intentions"`

"

> if I were to die at age of 19, then I’ll be scared even 1h before
>   death"

: Dude you will not  get a millisecond to repent. and Why would you be scared?. Dont say that
"   `I will die`" . As Muslims say "`My temporary life will be converted to permanent life "`

There was a pious man he told me that "`Allah give short life to test (good )people because he knew that if that person would be given 500 years he will not spend his life in  wrong things".`

There is a Hadith on Asking for Long-life:

> Imam Muslim reported that: "Umu-Habeebah, the prophet's wife said: "Oh Allah make my husband’s life long, {the messenger}, my father {Abu Sufian}, and my brother {Mu'awiah}.", the prophet (S.A.W.) replied: "You have asked Allah to change a previously dictated end, and a defined number of days, and an already apportioned sustenance (things that are already dictated). Allah (S.W.T.) will not hasten anything before its time, and He will not put off anything till after its time, but if you asked Allah (S.W.T.) to shelter you from Hell Fire, and protect you from the punishment of grave, it would have been better."

---

Lastly, for looking young in old age:

- Do exercise daily
- -Quit Smoking
- Eat Fruits+ dry fruits
- Drink Plenty of water (8-15 glass per day)

Hope I answered your question.